# Xamarin app crashes when a class is added as a property

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I apologize for the name, I would have titled it something more specific if I knew what to call it.

I am building a tasks/todo sort of app so I have a class for each task called Objective. I'm also using an SQLite database to persist the data. In `App.xaml.cs` in the `OnStart` method, I open a connection to the database and create a table of Objective objects. I'm not concerned about that being the culprit of the crash though because **until I added a new field to Objective, everything worked**. But once I added a field of type Auxiliary to Objective, the app would crash upon creating the table of objectives. The Auxiliary class is meant to hold information about settings for each objective but at the moment it only has a list of type string. I've made sure to comment out every instance of the Auxiliary being used throughout the application except for its instantiation.

The relevant parts of code:

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WelcomePage());
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
        var localDBManager = new LocalDBManager();
    }
}
```

LocalDBManager.cs

```
class LocalDBManager
{
    public static SQLiteAsyncConnection Connection;
    public static ObservableCollection<Objective> Objectives;
    public static ObservableCollection<Objective> IncompleteObjectives;
    public static ObservableCollection<Objective> CompleteObjectives;
    public static bool ObjectivesInitialized;

    public LocalDBManager()
    {
        Connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();

        Constructor();
    }

    private async void Constructor()
    {
        await Connection.CreateTableAsync<Objective>();

        var objectives = await Connection.Table<Objective>().ToListAsync();
        Objectives = new ObservableCollection<Objective>(objectives);

        ObjectivesInitialized = true;

        GetIncompleteObjectives();
        GetCompleteObjectives();
    }

    public async void GetIncompleteObjectives()
    {
        if (!ObjectivesInitialized)
        {
            var objectives = await Connection.Table<Objective>().ToListAsync();
            Objectives = new ObservableCollection<Objective>(objectives);
            ObjectivesInitialized = true;
        }


        var incompleteObjectivesIEnumerable = Objectives.Where(o => o.Completed == false).OrderBy(o => o.Name);
        IncompleteObjectives = new ObservableCollection<Objective>(incompleteObjectivesIEnumerable);
    }

    public async void GetCompleteObjectives()
    {
        if (!ObjectivesInitialized)
        {
            var objectives = await Connection.Table<Objective>().ToListAsync();
            Objectives = new ObservableCollection<Objective>(objectives);
            ObjectivesInitialized = true;
        }

        var completeObjectivesIEnumerable = Objectives.Where(o => o.Completed).OrderBy(o => o.Name);
        CompleteObjectives = new ObservableCollection<Objective>(completeObjectivesIEnumerable);
    }
}
```

Objective.cs

```
public class Objective
{
    public static int ObjectiveID;

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public bool Remind { get; set; }
    public DateTime RemindDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan RemindTime { get; set; }
    public bool Deadline { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeadlineDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan DeadlineTime { get; set; }
    public bool DeadlineEqualsRemind { get; set; }
    public string Aux { get; set; }
}
```

Auxiliary.cs

```
public class Auxiliary
{
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

There might be a fairly simple solution to this but it isn't coming to me. I'm still relatively new to c# so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: I realize that I did not include the exception**

The only information I get from the compliler is: "An unhandled exception occured." Through repeated tests, I found that the implementation of the Auxiliary field will crash the application. If there is any way to glean more information from xamarin's exceptions, I'd love to know because I tend to find them lacking.

Comment: you should start by identifying the exception causing the crash and the line that causes it - wrap the suspect code in a try/catch block

Comment: @Jason I edited the post with what little I have about the exception

Comment: that's what happens when you don't have any exception handling.  Use try/catch around the suspect code to identify the specific exception and line causing the issue

Comment: You area right @ZachZimmermann, the problem is the Auxiliary entity. The SQLite do those ORM things, and can't yet 'understand' nested complex types... If you want the 'Auxiliary' inside the 'Objective' class you can decorate the prop with `[Ignore]` attribute, so the SQLite will not interpret it like a field to db.